# Using np.where inside of df.eval string in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, eval

long time listener, first time caller..

I need to be able to call functions (custom made and otherwise, like numpy.where) as a string in a pandas dataframe eval statement.  see example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [[0,10,10],[1,20,20],[0,30,30]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['X','A','B'])


df['C'] = np.where(df.X==0,df.A+df.B,0) #This works

df['C'] = df.eval('np.where(X==0,A+B,0)') #But this is how i need to implement

df['C'] = df.eval('@np.where(X==0,A+B,0)') #pinata swings starting here
```

Please stackoverflow! help!

Comment: Remember the arguments of  a `where` are evaluated in full before being passed to the function.  This isn't some sort of iterative tool.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that.  I'm used to R where the vectorization is handled more elegantly.  It must be something about df.eval moreso than np.where that's causing the issue?

Comment: pandas adds whole nother layer of processsing to both numpy and python.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

I found a way to solve by changing the string and the way I evaluated to this:

```
df['C'] = eval("np.where(df['X']==0,df['A']+df['B'],0)")
```